# Are there symbols for optical systems like there are for electric circuits?

Tags: optics, terminology, notation

Do you now those electric circuits schematics, with symbols for resistors, cells, batteries, etc.? Is there something like that for optical lines, like symbols for polarisers, lasers sources, cameras, and prisms?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no universally used symbols for that. Although there are a few commonly used symbols in many publications, such as a square with a diagonal line through it for a beam splitter.

If I had to guess the reason why, it would be because while there are off-the-shelf optical components, they are not interchangeable to the degree in which electronic components are. Also, many optical systems are not position-independent like electronic circuits are. You can lengthen the wires of any circuit diagram and move the components around, and the circuit will not really change. But you can't do the same with a diagram of an optical system, at least not to the same degree.